# Parallaxing effect on Listview item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am developing an application in which `Listview` Contain Data, displaying with two images as shown in below images.

When I stretched thumb it display that Item on Full screen and remove other `ListView` Data.

I search lot with elastic and parallax but it shows only Header elastic but I want that effect on every List-Item and full that Item on Screen.

[image: click on thumb it stretch the item and display that Item in full screen]

Comment: basically what you need is another activity/fragment to display the image in full screen.

Comment: how you tried to show full view? can you explain

Comment: click on the thumb it stretch the image to top or bottom and that image display in another activity and  remove thumb.

Comment: this is what you are looking for - http://developer.android.com/training/transitions/index.html